# Tkinter pack() error argument method

Tags: python, tkinter, pack

I'm trying to make a GUI using TKinter and OOP (newbie).

```
from usuarios import Usuarios
from tkinter import *

class Application:

    def __init__(self, master = None):
        self.fonte = ('Verdana', '8')

        container1 = self.containerCreate(10)
        container2 = self.containerCreate(5, 20)
        container3 = self.containerCreate(5, 20)
        container4 = self.containerCreate(5, 20)
        container5 = self.containerCreate(5, 20)
        container6 = self.containerCreate(5, 20)
        container7 = self.containerCreate(5, 20)
        container8 = self.containerCreate(10, 20)
        container9 = self.containerCreate(10)

        lbl1 = self.labelCreate(container1, 'Informe os dados abaixo:', 'Calibri', '9', 'bold', LEFT)
#        lblUsuario = self.labelCreate(container2, 'idUsuário')

    def labelCreate(self, container, text, fonte, tamanho, estilo, alinhamento):
        self.lbl = Label(container, text)
        self.lbl['font'] = (fonte, tamanho, estilo)
        self.lbl.pack(side = alinhamento)


    def containerCreate(self, y = 0, x = 0, master = None):
        self.cont = Frame(master)
        self.cont['pady'] = y
        self.cont['padx'] = x
        self.cont.pack()

root = Tk()
Application(root)
root.mainloop()
```

I receive this error when I try to pass and argument to the `self.lbl.pack(alinhamento)` in the `labelCreate` method:

```
runfile('D:/Dropbox/Dropbox/Python/Tkinter/db Teste/App.py', wdir='D:/Dropbox/Dropbox/Python/Tkinter/db Teste')
Reloaded modules: usuarios, Banco
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-73-c94772663ba8>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('D:/Dropbox/Dropbox/Python/Tkinter/db Teste/App.py', wdir='D:/Dropbox/Dropbox/Python/Tkinter/db Teste')

  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 710, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 101, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "D:/Dropbox/Dropbox/Python/Tkinter/db Teste/App.py", line 44, in <module>
    Application(root)

  File "D:/Dropbox/Dropbox/Python/Tkinter/db Teste/App.py", line 27, in __init__
    lbl1 = self.labelCreate(container1, 'Informe os dados abaixo:', 'Calibri', '9', 'bold', LEFT)

  File "D:/Dropbox/Dropbox/Python/Tkinter/db Teste/App.py", line 32, in labelCreate
    self.lbl = Label(container, text)

  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2760, in __init__
    Widget.__init__(self, master, 'label', cnf, kw)

  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2289, in __init__
    classes = [(k, v) for k, v in cnf.items() if isinstance(k, type)]

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'items'
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not calling the `Label` widget constructor correctly. Here's some [documentation](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/label.html).

So here's how to do it (the `text=text` may look strange, but that's because you've given the positional parameter to `labelCreate()` function the same name as one of the `Label` widget constructor's *keyword* arguments:

```
    def labelCreate(self, container, text, fonte, tamanho, estilo, alinhamento):
#        self.lbl = Label(container, text)      # Wrong calling sequence!
        self.lbl = Label(container, text=text)  # Correct way.
        self.lbl['font'] = (fonte, tamanho, estilo)
        self.lbl.pack(side=alinhamento)
```